# Set values in Newform with CSR

Tags: 2013, javascript, jslink, client-side-rendering, newform

I have a `TestField` (Single line of text) that I can return a value to while in `NewForm.aspx`. The problem being, the TextBox disappears and it only displays the returned text itself.

```
(function () {
   var ctx = {};
   ctx.Templates = {};
   ctx.Templates.Fields = {
       'TestField': { 'NewForm': renderTestField }
   }

   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctx);
})();


function renderTestField(ctx)
{
   return 'TestText';

   //Will the below code work with a custom value in it??
   //return <input type="text" value="" maxlength="255" id="Dig_x0020_ID_b5482683-9113-41be-b2ea-8095919a2fd4_$TextField" title="Dig ID" class="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true">
}
```

I would like to return the text inside the original TextBox so the user can still edit it. What should my `renderTextField` function look like?

Should I return the original HTML which is being rendered? Do I need the long ID?

**EDIT:**
I tried returning the Original `<input>` HTML from the JSLink, but it doesn't save to the List Item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try as below

```
function renderTestField(ctx) {
    ctx.CurrentFieldValue = "TestText";
    return SPFieldText_Edit(ctx);
}
```

You can set custom value as below also

```
function renderTestField(ctx) {
    return '<input type="text" maxlength="255" id="Dig_x0020_ID_b5482683-9113-41be-b2ea-8095919a2fd4_$TextField" title="Dig ID" class="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true" value="TestValue"/>';
}
```

Comment: I tried this with multiple fields. Doesn't work :(

Comment: Textbox shows up, value is not applied. The value attribute is empty in the markup

Comment: If I use ctx.CurrentItem["TestField"] = 1, I can see this being set in my watch window but the field doesn't grab it

Comment: :) :) :) This solved multiple issues in one. Thanks once again Amal!

Comment: Amal, do you know function to call to return a Multi Line field? SPFieldText_Edit will return a single line.

Comment: I think it is `SPFieldNote_Edit`

Comment: That worked! I can't find this documented anywhere.